# What is a good place to store production logs of an ASP.NET application?

Tags: c#, asp.net, logging

**Environment:** Windows instance hosted in AWS.  ASP.NET application logs events and errors using log4net to an SQL Server database.

Now I'm looking to offload that logging to another server with the final goal of 1) reducing the load on the SQL Server and the server itself and 2) have a better way to search and analyze those logs, which are currently being stored in a non-indexed table.

I’m looking for something faster yet simple to install, configure and use. I've already investigated Seq, Logstash, and others, but none seem to fit my requirements very well. Can you suggest a solution?

The requirements:

- Free (and Open Source if possible)
- Runs on Windows
- Can be configured with log4net
- The server can be run on another server (or it has a minimal memory footprint)
- Fast

The good to haves:

- Minimal security to protect the server if it's public on the Internet.
- Supports event forwarding since the production server and the log server will be in loosely connected machines.
- UI with basic search & analytics

Answer (score 1):

One option is [Elasticsearch](https://www.elastic.co/products/elasticsearch) and [Kibana](https://www.elastic.co/products/elasticsearch). Use Google, but a good starting point for you could be http://www.ben-morris.com/using-logstash-elasticsearch-and-log4net-for-centralized-logging-in-windows/

The idea behind putting the logs in a search engine instead of into a database; is to make it easier to search your logs. You will get indexing on the fields you choose and full text search for free here. At the same time, Kibana provides an excellent user interface for exploring and aggregating logs.

My personal experience is that this makes for a very good logging setup that will make it easier for you to spot errors and negative trends faster.